# rails Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/controller/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am new to rails and i am trying to create a simple bookmark table:

```
  def up
create_table :bookmarks do |t|
    t.string  :path,        :null => false
    t.integer :user_id,     :null => false

    t.timestamps
end

add_index :bookmarks, :user_id
add_index :bookmarks, :path
  end
```

then i have this in my contoller:

```
    # GET bookmark/new
# GET bookmark/new.json
def new
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new
end

# POST bookmark/new
# POST bookmark/new.json
def create
    @bookmark = Bookmark.new(params[:bookmark])
    if @bookmark.save
        flash[:success] = "Bookmark Saved"
    else
        flash[:failure] = "Failed !"
    end
end
```

and my view is this:

```
<%= form_for :bookmark do |bookmark| %>
<%= bookmark.label :path %>
<%= bookmark.text_field :path %>

<%= bookmark.label :user_id %>
<%= bookmark.text_field :user_id %>

<%= bookmark.submit "Add bookmark" %>
<% end %>
```

finally running rake routes gets this list of routes:

```
          bookmark_index GET    /bookmark(.:format)            bookmark#index
                     POST   /bookmark(.:format)            bookmark#create
        new_bookmark GET    /bookmark/new(.:format)        bookmark#new
       edit_bookmark GET    /bookmark/:id/edit(.:format)   bookmark#edit
            bookmark GET    /bookmark/:id(.:format)        bookmark#show
                     PUT    /bookmark/:id(.:format)        bookmark#update
                     DELETE /bookmark/:id(.:format)        bookmark#destroy
```

**and when i try to submit the form i get this error:**

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/bookmark/new"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

**Edit:**

Changing :bookmark to @bookmark throws this error:

```
    NoMethodError in Bookmark#new

Showing /media/wahtver/600415AD27D78282/3pces/pces/app/views/shared/_bookmark_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `bookmarks_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003a48398>:0x007f1034b6b908>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for @bookmark do |bookmark| %>
2:  <%= bookmark.label :path %>
3:  <%= bookmark.text_field :path %>
4:
```

what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for @bookmark do |bookmark| %>
```

and not

```
<%= form_for :bookmark do |bookmark| %>
```

Look more closely at the error message. It's using `POST`, not `GET`.

edit: Your routes should be `resources :bookmarks`.

When you run `rake routes` it should give you:

`bookmarks GET    /bookmarks(.:format)            bookmarks#index`

Comment: changed the line, now it throws this error `NoMethodError in Bookmark#new` on the `form_for' line.

Comment: You made a mistake in your routes. Can you post the part about bookmarks? You should have `resources :bookmarks`

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare your routes? Did you have on your route.rb file `resource :bookmark` or `resources :bookmarks`?

If you see your controller in your create method you have this:

```
# POST bookmark/new
# POST bookmark/new.json
def create
```

Pay attention to the comments that rails generate automatically above each method when you use scaffold (i guess you generated the controller with scaffold), it should be `POST /bookmarks` or `POST /bookmark`. If you used scaffold for some reason rails generated bad that route.

Show your `routes.rb` file.